# Cannot get the result from firebase and show in alert dialog

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm new in developing android app and now I'm currently doing a project that uses `barcode scanner` using `Zxing` library to scan the barcode and from the barcode number that it gets, it will compare with the barcode number that I create in `Firebase real-time database` and retrieve the related information of the barcode number.

But now I cannot get the retrieved information in an alert dialog and during the debug this code:

```
reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product");
```

shows null. I'm hoping that someone can help me with this problem. Thank you

Here is the code:

```
 public void handleResult(final Result rawResult) {

    final String result = rawResult.getText();

    Log.e("QRCodeScanner", rawResult.getText());
    Log.e("QRCodeScanner", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product");
    reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String Barcode = data.getValue().toString();

                if (Barcode.equals(rawResult.getText())){
                    String ProductName = dataSnapshot.child("ProductName").getValue().toString();

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BarcodeScannerActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
                    builder.setMessage(ProductName);
                    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                    alert1.show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Below is my `Firebase real-time database` structure:

```
{
  "Product" : {

    "Product1" : {
      "Barcode" : 112233,
      "MemPrice" : 5,
      "Price" : 10,
      "ProductName" : "Logitech"
    },
    "Product2" : {
      "Barcode" : 123456,
      "MemPrice" : 5000,
      "Price" : 10000,
      "ProductName" : "Dell"
    },
    "Product3" : {
      "Barcode" : 778899,
      "MemPrice" : 150,
      "Price" : 300,
      "ProductName" : "BenQ"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: edited my post~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
String Barcode = data.getValue().toString();
if (Barcode.equals(rawResult.getText())){
String ProductName = dataSnapshot.child("ProductName").getValue().toString();
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BarcodeScannerActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
                    builder.setMessage(ProductName);
                    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                    alert1.show();
}
```

into this:

```
String Barcode = data.child("Barcode").getValue(String.class);
if (Barcode.equals(rawResult.getText())){
String ProductName = data.child("ProductName").getValue(String.class);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BarcodeScannerActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
                    builder.setMessage(ProductName);
                    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                    alert1.show();
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but after scanning the barcode it stuck at there and did not pop out the alert dialog

Comment: Is there any mistake that make by me because after I change the code it still stuck at the scan page after it get the barcode

Comment: u are not navigating to any other activity in your code..it should show an alert in the current activity..